# ParseKit rev. 74 not working?

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

I downloaded ParseKit using command 
svn checkout http://todparsekit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ todparsekit-read-only
revision number is 74. I tried to run DemoApp. Application started up. When I pushed Parse button, no tree was displayed. 
After setting USE_TRACK to 1, it displayed log like

```
After : [ 42
Expected : CaseInsensitiveLiteral ]
Found : e-12
```

Seems to me that handling of 'Number' has changed. When I tried to use same ParseKit code in my own project, ParseKit threw exception when parsing '0.8' as Number.

I might be missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Developer of ParseKit here. Thanks for the heads up. I have fixed the issue.

The problem was:

The new `-[PKNumberState allowsFloatingPoint]` method should default to `YES`, but when creating a parser via the ParserFactory (a grammar), it was defaulting to `NO`.

The fix is checked in as rev 78.